# Relative row_number() in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
SessionID    URL              created    rownum
abc   www.google.com/page1    2016-08-01   1
abc   www.google.com/page2    2016-08-02   2
abc   www.google.com/blah     2016-08-03   3
abc   www.google.com/page3    2016-08-04   4
abc   www.google.com/page4    2016-08-05   5
```

and I would like to have an output that looks like this:

```
SessionID    URL               created   rownum  newrownum
abc   www.google.com/page1    2016-08-01   1    -2
abc   www.google.com/page2    2016-08-02   2    -1
abc   www.google.com/blah     2016-08-03   3    0
abc   www.google.com/page3    2016-08-04   4    1
abc   www.google.com/page4    2016-08-05   5    2
```

In other words, I would like to see where a `session` is visiting a particular page `blah` and I'd like to see the pages visited before and after this particular page. Notice that the pages in the `session` are ordered as per the `created` field.

I generated the `rownum` column using the following query:

```
select 
    sessionid, 
    url, 
    created,
    row_number() over(partition by sessionid order by created) as rownum
from 
    <tablename>
order by 
    sessionid, 
    created
```

I'm not sure how to get the row numbers that are negative values with respect to a certain page. This is required so I can plot the kind of pages that are visited before and after the page `blah`. Of course, there can be multiple visits to the same page `blah` in the same session. In such a case, the first visit should be treated as the zeroth visit (with a value 0 in `newrownum` column).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select sessionid, url, created, rownum,
       (rownum - min(case when url = 'blah' then rownum end) over (partition by sessionid) as newrownum
from (select sessionid, url, created,
             row_number() over (partition by sessionid order by created) as rownum
      from <tablename>
     ) t
order by sessionid, created;
```

In other words, this calculates the row number for 'blah' using another window function.  In more recent versions of Postgres, you can use the `filter` keyword rather than the `case` statement for the conditional min.

Note:  This does the offset from the first occurrence of `'blah'`, because of the `min()`.  The last occurrence would use `max()`.  And, your actual logic might use something like `url like '%blah'` or something with the full pathname.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a simple answer, it makes a lot of sense. Worked like a charm :).

Answer (score 2):

You can subtract the rownum of blah from the already calculated rownum column for each session.

```
select t.*, rownum-max(case when url like '%blah%' then rownum end) over(partition by sessionid) newrownum
from (
select 
    sessionid, 
    url, 
    created,
    row_number() over(partition by sessionid order by created) as rownum
from 
    <tablename>
) t
order by rownum
```

To get the exact pattern match of url containing `blah` use a regex, something like `url ~ '.+/blah$'`

Answer (score 1):

Apply an offset based on the row number of the page you want to use as your baseline (your row 0). In this case, you could create a new field as rownum - 3 to achieve the values you are looking for.